# How to ensure that all pre-commit hooks pass in CI/CD

Tags: pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

My team uses [Pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) in our repositories to run various code checks and formatters. Most of my teammates use it but some skip it entirely by committing with `git commit --no-verify`. Is there anyway to run something in CI/CD to ensure all Pre-commit hooks pass (we're using GitHub actions). If at least one hooks fails, then throw an error.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are several choices:

- an adhoc job which runs `pre-commit run --all-files` as [demonstrated in pre-commit.com docs](https://pre-commit.com/#usage-in-continuous-integration) (you probably also want `--show-diff-on-failure` if you're using formatters)
- [pre-commit.ci](https://pre-commit.ci/) a CI system specifically built for this purpose
- [pre-commit/action](https://github.com/pre-commit/action) a github action which is in maintenance-only mode (not recommended for new usecases)

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit, and pre-commit.ci, and the github action